# Tunnel all traffic through VPN except a specific network

Tags: vpn, route, openconnect

I am using openconnect on a remote CentOS 7.5 to connect to a VPN on another network. When I ssh to that machine and connect to VPN, my ssh connection breaks. Both my CentOS and desktop machines are on 10.1.1.x zone. How can I add exception to openconnect so outgoing and incoming traffic for internal network is not routed through VPN?